# I would like to get top 10 score from my database table in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my query:

```java
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +Apputil.TABLE_HIGHSCORE +
                     " WHERE " + Apputil.KEY_USER + " = 'Single'" +
                     " ORDER BY " + Apputil.KEY_PLAYER1SCORE+" DESC", null);
```

How can I limit this to 10 rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to limit 10 in this query

Add `LIMIT 10` at the end, after the `ORDER BY ... DESC`.

Comment: Thanks and i got solution before your answer but thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hm, I posted the answer a minute and 9 seconds after your question so rhetorically asking, if you got the answer yourself in that time, did it make sense to post the question?